# Theme deactived html and css styling on home page posts

Tags: plugins, css, html

I'm a designer trying to learn php, so I can't fully understand where the problem is coming from. That being said, I have a theme that has deactivated the use of css styling on the main page where posts are mainly displayed. This is the (f8) lite theme by the way. I want to create links useing divs and what not, but when i throw in the code it dosent show up. But when you enter the post the css is rendered out perfectly.

I think the culprit has something to do with the plugin it comes ingrained with called "get the image". And no there arn't any options to turn off the plugin. Please if anyone has any ideas, please fire away. 
And TIA

Comment: What do you mean "There aren't any options to turn off the plugin"? 

Do you mean that the plug-in won't deactivate or that the plug-in is required and deactivating it isn't an option?

Comment: What do you mean "has deactivated the use of css styling on the main page"? What do you mean "create links useing (sic) divs and what not"? When you say "throw in the code", what specifically do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Reido, you're most likely facing an incompability between some stuff of your wordpress installation, for example, between theme and a plugin or even between theme, plugin and wordpress.

Just disable the plugin and check if the problem still exists. If so, disable all plugins, and try again. You need to find which component is incompatible and then just do not use it any longer or fix it.

For getting a plugin fixed you can try to find support for a plugin or you can contact someone who is firm with PHP and wordpress plugin programming. So if you just learn PHP you can try to learn PHP by fixing it on your own, sure.

You can get help on hacking plugins in the [wordpress support forums](http://wordpress.org/support/) as well.